# Select value and column that value have changed

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a historian that is logging 1 row each time 1 of the value changes. So in each Row there should always only 1 value that has changed from the previous Row

My table looks like this. (i have more than 5 Columns and they don't have generic name, these column name will change for each project. I'd like to avoid hardcoding Column name)

```
INDEX|Column1|Column2|Column3|Column4|Column5|TimeStamp 
1    |      0|      0|      0|      0|      0|2017-03-28 13:00:00
2    |      0|      0|      0|      1|      0|2017-03-28 14:00:00
3    |      2|      0|      0|      1|      0|2017-03-28 15:00:00
4    |      3|      0|      0|      1|      0|2017-03-28 16:00:00
5    |      3|     22|      0|      1|      0|2017-03-28 17:00:00
6    |      3|     22|      6|      1|      0|2017-03-28 18:00:00
```

The result i want to get in my report.

```
Name   |NewValue|PreviousValue|TimeStamp
Column4|       1|            0|2017-03-28 14:00:00
Column1|       2|            0|2017-03-28 15:00:00
Column1|       3|            2|2017-03-28 16:00:00
Column2|      22|            0|2017-03-28 17:00:00
Column3|       6|            0|2017-03-28 18:00:00
```

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Im using MariaDB 10.1.22.

Comment: how many columns do you have in total?

Comment: i have about 30 Column, the number and name of the column will vary in each project id like to avoid hardcoding column Name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Using Static SQL:

This is the basic code you want. But everything is hardcoded. That cannot be avoided without "dynamic SQL".

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN t1.Column1 <> t2.Column1 THEN 'Column1'
    WHEN t1.Column2 <> t2.Column2 THEN 'Column2'    
    WHEN t1.Column3 <> t2.Column3 THEN 'Column3'
    WHEN t1.Column4 <> t2.Column4 THEN 'Column4'
    WHEN t1.Column5 <> t2.Column5 THEN 'Column5'
END as Name,
CASE
    WHEN t1.Column1 <> t2.Column1 THEN t2.Column1
    WHEN t1.Column2 <> t2.Column2 THEN t2.Column2   
    WHEN t1.Column3 <> t2.Column3 THEN t2.Column3
    WHEN t1.Column4 <> t2.Column4 THEN t2.Column4
    WHEN t1.Column5 <> t2.Column5 THEN t2.Column5
END as NewValue,
CASE
    WHEN t1.Column1 <> t2.Column1 THEN t1.Column1
    WHEN t1.Column2 <> t2.Column2 THEN t1.Column2   
    WHEN t1.Column3 <> t2.Column3 THEN t1.Column3
    WHEN t1.Column4 <> t2.Column4 THEN t1.Column4
    WHEN t1.Column5 <> t2.Column5 THEN t1.Column5
END as PreviousValue,
t2.TimeStamp
FROM
MyTable t1
JOIN MyTable t2
    ON t2.Index = t1.Index + 1
```

If it's possible for the columns to be `NULL` either before or after, you'll need to adjust the `<>`s accordingly.

### Using Dynamic SQL:

Rather than hard-code the column names, you can generate code like the above by extracting column data from the `information_schema` tables. Set the `@tablename` variable to the name of the table you wish to process, and this code will set the variable `@sql` to hold code equivalent to that above. I've used `\n` to add new lines and so improve the formatting in the generated code.

```
-- Avoids the GROUP_CONCAT truncating the code we're building
SET SESSION GROUP_CONCAT_MAX_LEN=65535;

-- Specify your target table here
SELECT @tablename := 'MyTable';

SELECT @sql := GROUP_CONCAT(theCode SEPARATOR '')
FROM
(
-- theOrderBy is for keeping the various parts of this code in the correct sequence
-- SELECT plus the opening of the first CASE statement
SELECT 0 theOrderBy, 'SELECT\nCASE\n' theCode

UNION ALL

-- Generates the inner part first CASE statement
SELECT 1, CONCAT('    WHEN t1.',Column_Name,' <> t2.',Column_Name,' THEN ''', Column_Name,'''','\n')
FROM `information_schema`.`Columns`
WHERE table_name like @tablename
AND Column_Name NOT IN ('Index','Timestamp')

UNION ALL

-- Generates the end of the first CASE (and it's alias) and the beginning of the second one
SELECT 2, 'END as Name,\nCASE\n'

UNION ALL

-- Generates the inner part second CASE statement
SELECT 3, CONCAT('    WHEN t1.',Column_Name,' <> t2.',Column_Name,' THEN t2.', Column_Name, '\n')
from `information_schema`.`Columns`
WHERE table_name LIKE @tablename
AND Column_Name NOT IN ('Index','Timestamp')

UNION ALL

-- Generates the end of the second CASE (and it's alias) and the beginning of the third one    
SELECT 4, 'END as NewValue,\nCASE\n'

UNION ALL

-- Generates the inner part third CASE statement
SELECT 5, CONCAT('    WHEN t1.',Column_Name,' <> t2.',Column_Name,' THEN t1.', Column_Name, '\n')
FROM `information_schema`.`Columns`
WHERE table_name like @tablename
AND Column_Name NOT IN ('Index','Timestamp')

UNION ALL

-- Generates the end of the final CASE statement plus the FROM clause
SELECT 6, CONCAT('END as PreviousValue,\nt2.Timestamp\nFROM\n    ',@tablename, ' t1\n    JOIN ',@tablename, ' t2 ON\n        t2.Index = t1.Index + 1')

ORDER BY theOrderBy
) as sub;

SELECT @sql;
```

If you're happy with what you see in the variable, you can re-run replacing the last line with:

```
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

The viability of this code depends heavily on your having the same essential structure for any targetted table, namely a sequentially increasing `Index` field and a `Timestamp`. As in the "Static" code, this is also using `<>` for all the comparisons, so effectively assuming the fields will not be `NULL` either before or after each change.

If those assumptions don't hold, you'll need to make adjustments. If you need help with that, do let me know.

Comment: I replaced `before` and `after` with `t1` and `t2` since the originals are reserved words.

Comment: I've now also added a version using dynamic SQL. It depends heavily on your having the same essential structure for any targetted table, namely a sequentially increasing "index" field and a "timestamp". I've also stuck with `<>` so if you have `NULL`s you may need to change that, which could be a little complex and how it's done will depend on data types. If they are all numeric as in your example it wouldn't be too bad.

Comment: I made some minor amendments to improve the formatting in the generated SQL, and to add a little "narrative" to make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 'Column5', column5, max(timestamp) from mytable where column5 <> 0 group by column5
Union
SELECT 'Column4', column4, max(timestamp) from mytable where column4 <> 0 group by column4
Union
SELECT 'Column3', column3, max(timestamp) from mytable where column3 <> 0 group by column3
Union
SELECT 'Column2', column2, max(timestamp) from mytable where column2 <> 0 group by column2
Union
SELECT 'Column1', column1, max(timestamp) from mytable where column1 <> 0 group by column1
```

Comment: @no666 Oh didnt see your comment prior to posting, let me recheck